# how to update row with data from another and already updated row in the same update command SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have to update a row using the value i've already updated in a previous row. Weird to write so i'll show an example:

```
create table #temp (col1 int, col2 int)

insert into #temp values(1, 2)
insert into #temp values(2, 4)
insert into #temp values(3, 6)

update T set 
col2 = case when col1 = 1 then 3 else (select col2 from #temp where col1 = 1) * col2 end 
from #temp T
```

What i get for result is:

```
col1        col2
----------- -----------
1           3
2           8
3           12
```

and what i need is:

```
col1        col2
----------- -----------
1           3
2           12
3           18
```

There's something like NEW.value in this context?

PS: I know the values in this example are statics, but in my actual code their not. Suppose the value of col2 in the first record is unknown

Comment: If you are hardcoding the value for the first row 3 then why don't you just use col2*3 for the other rows?

Comment: That's cause this example doesn't look like the actual procedure. The actual code won't use any static value

Comment: And how it is supposed to get the first value then?, cause you should store it into a variable and use it in the `UPDATE`.

Comment: All the rows are updated concurrently. There is no order. The concept of "value i've already updated in a previous row" doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: Imagine i have 2 tables and i'm updating both of them (through a join) in the first row, but in the second one i need to use the updated value of the second table to get the right results

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want something like this?

```
create table #temp (col1 int, col2 int)

insert into #temp values(1, 2)
insert into #temp values(2, 4)
insert into #temp values(3, 6)

DECLARE @cvalue int;
select @cvalue = 3;

update T set 
col2 = case when col1 = 1 then @cvalue else @cvalue * col2 end 
from #temp T

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Basically, you get the value you want to remain constant throughout the update first and put it into a variable, and then use that variable in the update.

Please note that there is no way to calculate a value that is assigned to one column, and then use the value of that column in other calculations in the same update statement.  That would be a violation of how SQL is designed to work (and if that DID work, it'd break a ton of other queries and updates).  This is called "The Halloween Problem" and you can read about it here, and how SQL Server deliberately avoids the 'cascading update' issue you seem to want here:
http://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/halloween-problem-part-1

Comment: Actually no. The value of the first update (3) isn't going to be static. It will be the result of a complex calculation, which i don't want to repeat in the next rows updates

Comment: Again, this was just an example... you calculate the value once and use it in the update.  If that won't work, then your question is unclear and you should provide a more representative example... because this solution works for the schema, data, and query you provided.  I can only answer the actual question you asked, and not the unknown question still in your head.

Comment: Imagine i have 2 tables and i'm updating both of them (through a join) in the first row, but in the second one i need to use the updated value of the second table to get the right results

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bother guys... I've found an answer to my problem. Here's an example:

```
create table #temp (col1 int, col2 int)

declare @var int = 3

insert into #temp values(1, 2)
insert into #temp values(2, 4)
insert into #temp values(3, 6)

update T set 
col2 = @var * col2,
@var = @var - 1 
from #temp T
```

Comment: This method is named [quirky update](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) and it has some cons. Please read.

Comment: No offense, but this 'answer' doesn't seem to have any relation to the question, which was not about "how do I modify a variable for each row in a select" but "how do I get the value I just assigned to a previous column within that same update"... You really needed a far better statement of the question, with ACTUAL data and ACTUAL queries, so people could understand and help.